# is there any way to restrict certain user from DDL and DML oprations on existing objects but allowing to create his their own objects

Tags: sql-server, ddl, dml

is there any way to restrict certain user from DDL and DML operations on existing objects but allowing them to create their own objects and do DDL and DML with these new objects also the user should able to read old tables in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

One way is to give them all the permissions you want them to have at the database or schema level, and then individually DENY them the permissions you don't want them to have on all the existing objects.

Comment: my schema is same and if i give only read/write permission then that user will not able to create his own objects

Comment: By "full read/write", I mean full permission to create, alter, execute, etc.

Comment: If I give full permission then that user will able to drop/alter existing objects.
I want to avoid that and the user should able to drop/alter his objects not existing ones.

Comment: You are focusing too much on a literal interpretation of my words.   I will re-word the answer to be more literal.   Besides which, you are wrong, in my answer I stated that you should explicitly DENY the permission to ALTER/DROP existing objects.

Comment: can you please tell me how to DENY the permission  ALTER/DROP existing objects explicitly because I am not aware how to do that.

Thanks in advance